# Read stream using transferUtility.BeginOpenStream in the callback function

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do I access the S3 file stream when using `transferUtility.BeginOpenStream(request, callback, state)`?

In my async callback function I have an IAsyncResult paramter, but it doesn't provides any access to the stream to be read.

I am using the C#/.NET AWS SDK

Answer (score 0):

You usually need to call something like `transferUtility.EndOpenStream(asyncResult)` and that should give you your result.